# How to make a border going left and right like a snake around my articles list?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a line that go around my articles like a snake that go left and right.
To achieve that, I have tried the code below :

```css
.article-container{
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 5px solid #df9b35;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #df9b35;
}


.article-container.left{
      border-left: 5px solid #df9b35;
      padding-left: 30px;
      border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
}


.article-container.right{
      border-right: 5px solid #df9b35;
      padding-right: 30px;
      border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="article-container left">
    <article>
      <header>
        <h1>Article 1</h1>
        <time datetime="2022-08-18 15:55">18 August</time>
      </header>
      <p>Short description here</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="article-container right">
    <article>
      <header>
        <h1>Article 2</h1>
        <time datetime="2022-08-18 16:00">18 August</time>
      </header>
      <p>Short description here</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="article-container left">
    <article>
      <header>
        <h1>Article 3</h1>
        <time datetime="2022-08-18 16:05">18 August</time>
      </header>
      <p>Short description here</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

But as you can see, the problem here is that the border continue all along the container and don't stop before the next border radius. So, I don't have the continuous line that I'm searching for.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do this with borders on the elements themselves. Perhaps pseudo-elements at either end and then borders on those. Have to think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neat way to make this work would be to make use of pseudo-elements like `::before` or `::after` in which you could display the border with an offset on the sides that you simply can't achieve when relying on the box-model.

It would look like this:

```css
.article-container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.article-container:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.article-container::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #df9b35;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #df9b35;
}

.article-container.left {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.article-container.left::before {
  right: 50px;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid #df9b35;
  border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

.article-container.right {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.article-container.right::before {
  left: 50px;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 5px solid #df9b35;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="article-container left">
    <article class="card-container time-item">
      <header>
        <h1>Article 1</h1>
        <time datetime="2022-08-18 15:55">18 August</time>
      </header>
      <p>Short description here</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="article-container right">
    <article class="card-container time-item">
      <header>
        <h1>Article 2</h1>
        <time datetime="2022-08-18 16:00">18 August</time>
      </header>
      <p>Short description here</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="article-container left">
    <article class="card-container time-item">
      <header>
        <h1>Article 3</h1>
        <time datetime="2022-08-18 16:05">18 August</time>
      </header>
      <p>Short description here</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

The relative positioning on all of the `.article-container` is critical for this to work and the negative bottom margin makes it so that the top and bottom borders are aligned.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, It works great even in responsive mode, perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution where I removed the left and right borders from the divs and added pseudo-elements instead which also contain the border "curves". Takes some tweaking of the positions etc., and (if you want the very end of the line to lead all the way to the side of the container) especially the very last `: before` element depends on whether it's a left or right element, so you might have to tweak that additionally.

```css
.article-container {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #df9b35;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #df9b35;
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

.article-container:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.article-container.left:first-child:before {
 position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -5px;
  right: -40px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  border-top: 5px solid #df9b35;
  }
.article-container.left:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -5px;
  left: -40px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
  border-left: 5px solid #df9b35;
  border-top: 5px solid #df9b35;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #df9b35;
}

.article-container.right:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -5px;
  right: -40px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
  border-right: 5px solid #df9b35;
  border-top: 5px solid #df9b35;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #df9b35;
}
.article-container.left:last-child:before {
 position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0px;
  right: -40px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #df9b35;
  }
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="article-container left">
    <article class="card-container time-item">
      <header>
        <h1>Article 1</h1>
        <time datetime="2022-08-18 15:55">18 August</time>
      </header>
      <p>Short description here</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="article-container right">
    <article class="card-container time-item">
      <header>
        <h1>Article 2</h1>
        <time datetime="2022-08-18 16:00">18 August</time>
      </header>
      <p>Short description here</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="article-container left">
    <article class="card-container time-item">
      <header>
        <h1>Article 3</h1>
        <time datetime="2022-08-18 16:05">18 August</time>
      </header>
      <p>Short description here</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :)
You and Maxime have rapidly come to the same solution in the same time, but because you have a lot of karma, I have accepted the response from Maxime ^^

Comment: There is a little difference in our solutions: Mine includes additional pseudo elements (`before`)  which make sure the first and last line reach to the side of the container.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that in the first place, but your solution is better in that aspect, thanks for mention it.

Answer (score 1):

```
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.article-container {
  padding: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 2 * 50px);  /* 2 * border-radius */

}

.article-container.left {
  border-left: 5px solid #df9b35;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
  position: relative;
  left:-25px; /* shift left border-radius/2 */
  border-top: 5px solid #df9b35;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #df9b35;
}

.article-container.right {
/*   border-right: 5px solid #df9b35; */
  padding-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
  position: relative;
  right:-25px;  /* shift right border-radius/2 */
  box-shadow: 0px -5px 0px 0px #df9b35, 5px 5px 0px 0px #df9b35;  
  /* this will overlap the other article's border */
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/shaniemoonlight/pen/dymwgqE)

Comment: Simpler alternative! I didn't fully understand why you're using box-shadow only in the right border.

Comment: The border is included in the height of the element but shadow is not. The shadow will just spill out OVER the neighboring element and will blend in with the other borders if they are the same size and color.